# Python Regex: How do I use regular expression to read in a text file and extract only the names from any lines that contains 2 names

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, findall

Suppose I only need the lines in a txt file that contain two names such as:

```
<td >Jacob</td> <td>273,844</td> <td >Emily</td> <td>223,690</td></tr>
```

And the txt file contains the text below:

```
<tr >

     <th style="text-align:right; background-color:white; color:black" scope="col">Rank</th>

     <th style="text-align:right; background-color:white; color:black" scope="col" abbr="male name">Name</th>

     <th style="text-align:right; background-color:white; color:black" scope="col" abbr="male number">Number</th>

     <th style="text-align:right; background-color:white; color:black"  scope="col" abbr="female name">Name</th>

     <th style="text-align:right; background-color:white; color:black"  abbr="female number">Number</th>

   </tr>

   </thead>

   <tbody>

<tr ><td>1</td>

  <td >Jacob</td> <td>273,844</td> <td >Emily</td> <td>223,690</td></tr>

<tr ><td>2</td>

  <td >Michael</td> <td>250,554</td> <td >Madison</td> <td>193,152</td></tr>

<tr ><td>3</td>

  <td >Joshua</td> <td>231,926</td> <td >Emma</td> <td>181,257</td></tr>

<tr ><td>4</td>

  <td >Matthew</td> <td>221,513</td> <td >Olivia</td> <td>156,000</td></tr>

<tr ><td>5</td>
```

Using the regex `"^<td\s*>([a-zA-Z]+)<\/td\s*>.*<td\s*>([a-zA-Z]+)<\/td\s*>.*"`
how do I extract the **names** only using **re.findall** to compile a list?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it need to be a regular expression? Couldn't something like `'<td >Jacob</td>' in line or '<td >Emily</td>' in line`, where `line` is an individual line in the file, suffice?

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb Yes this needs to be done in regular expression. Supposedly it could be done in one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1

I guess, you can simply call that using your expression, or maybe a bit modified version of that, such as with:

```
^\h*<td\s*>([^<\r\n]+)<\/td\s*>.*<td\s*>([^<\r\n]+)<\/td\s*>
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mc2gpv/1/)

#### Test 1

```
import re

string = '''
<tr >

     <th style="text-align:right; background-color:white; color:black" scope="col">Rank</th>

     <th style="text-align:right; background-color:white; color:black" scope="col" abbr="male name">Name</th>

     <th style="text-align:right; background-color:white; color:black" scope="col" abbr="male number">Number</th>

     <th style="text-align:right; background-color:white; color:black"  scope="col" abbr="female name">Name</th>

     <th style="text-align:right; background-color:white; color:black"  abbr="female number">Number</th>

   </tr>

   </thead>

   <tbody>

<tr ><td>1</td>

  <td >Jacob</td> <td>273,844</td> <td >Emily</td> <td>223,690</td></tr>

<tr ><td>2</td>

  <td >Michael</td> <td>250,554</td> <td >Madison</td> <td>193,152</td></tr>

<tr ><td>3</td>

  <td >Joshua</td> <td>231,926</td> <td >Emma</td> <td>181,257</td></tr>

<tr ><td>4</td>

  <td >Matthew</td> <td>221,513</td> <td >Olivia</td> <td>156,000</td></tr>

<tr ><td>5</td>
'''

print(re.findall(r'<td\s*>([a-zA-Z]+)<\/td\s*>.*<td\s*>([a-zA-Z]+)<\/td\s*>.*', string))
```

#### Output 1

```
[('Jacob', 'Emily'), ('Michael', 'Madison'), ('Joshua', 'Emma'), ('Matthew', 'Olivia')]
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Mc2gpv/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/Mc2gpv/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### Method 2

Maybe, a better approach would be to use `bs4` though:

#### Test 2

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('/path/to/your/filename.txt', 'r+b')
names = []
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')
finally:
    f.close()

    for l in soup.find_all('td'):
        if re.match(r'\D+', l.text):
            names.append(l.text)
print(names)
```

#### Output 2

```
['Jacob', 'Emily', 'Michael', 'Madison', 'Joshua', 'Emma', 'Matthew', 'Olivia']
```

Comment: I've tried that and it's only returning empty list.

Comment: is it possible to do this code by inputing a file?